# EF4.1 Data is not updating (is not saved to database)

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have simple method to update user rating:

```
        public void PostScore(int userId, GlobalSettings gs, string name)
    {
        User user = _usrRepo.GetById(userId);
        if (name == "up")
        {
            user.Rating = user.Rating + gs.ScoreForLike;
        }
        else if (name == "down")
        {
            user.Rating = user.Rating - Math.Abs(gs.ScoreForDislike);
        }
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The problem is, that user rating do not update.. I mean the changes are not saved to database. 
Is there way to debug what's going and and why EF4.1 do not save data to database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your are getting your `User` object through a repository (`_usrRepo`) that is using a different context than the one you are are calling `SaveChanges()` on (`_ctx`) - I bet this is your problem.